# Javascript script not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a snippet of javascript that doesn't seem to be working in safari but it works in all other browsers.

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var contracts = $.evalJSON($("#json_contracts").val());
            var contractDropDown = $("#<%= c.cID%>");
            var dateDropDown = $("#<%= _startDate.cID %>");

            function populateMonths(i) {

                dateDropDown.empty();

                if (i == 0) {
                    dateDropDown.append("<option value=\"Select Month\">Select Month</option>");
                    return;
                }

                $(contracts[i-1].AvailableBillingMonths).each(function(j) {
                    var selected = "";
                    dateDropDown.append("<option value=\"" + contracts[i-1].AvailableBillingMonths[j].InvoiceMonth + "\" " + selected + ">" + contracts[i-1].AvailableBillingMonths[j].InvoiceMonth + "</option>");
                });
            }

            contractDropDown.click(function() {
                populateMonths(this.selectedIndex || 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Can anyone see why it wouldn't be working?  The whole point of this snippet is to populate the date dropdown with the correct months, but it never actually populates it in safari.

Comment: Any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Which part of it isn't working? Have you checked whether `contractDropDown` and `dateDropDown` actually select the elements they're supposed to? (More generally -- [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/))

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Check for errors in console. And try replacing the click with change event  contractDropDown.change(

Comment: try to define the function outside the ready statement.. anything changed?

Comment: `$.evalJSON()`? Why use a plugin? What version of jQuery are you using anyway?

Comment: @Sushanth-- thanks that was the issue.  if you make an answer I will accept it.  Safari wasn't recognizing .click()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the **click** event with the **change** event ..

Try this

```
contractDropDown.change(function() {
```